# $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}, \frac{p^p+1}{p+1} $ cannot be prime power at the same time

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$p\gt3$ is a prime, then the two numbers 
$$\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}, \; \frac{p^p+1}{p+1} $$
cannot be [prime power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_power) at the same time

I have no clue about it. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint: p is prime > 3. This means p is odd. Hence $p^p+1$ admits a factorization in terms of (p+1) ... do the same for $p^p-1$.

Comment: Try computing the greatest common divisor of the two numbers...

Comment: @IgorRivin i don't get and what if we compute the $\gcd$?

Comment: @panoramix It allows you to simplify the expansions: $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a\pmod b,b)$. At the same time, the final result also answers the question.

Comment: @YongHaoNg i think that it does not matter if we compute the $\gcd$.  If it is $1$  how this rejects the case that the first number is $q^a$ and the second $r^b$ with $q,r$ being primes?

Comment: @panoramix I think I misinterpreted the question. I thought the goal is to show that they cannot be of the form $q^a,q^b$.

Comment: @YongHaoNg i think that both of the 2 commentators above also misunderstood the question.:)

Comment: Is any p known, such that one of the given expressions is a nontrivial primepower (a primepower, but not a prime) ?